# Visual Studio 2013 + Business Intelligence SSDT and missing Reporting Server templates

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

The other day I have installed [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42313)  (SSDT: Replacement for BIDS) and started using reporting features in **VS2013**.

However, later on I needed SQL Server 2014, then I downloaded and installed the developer edition. (in case if this my caused the problem)

Now the **Report Server Project** templates are missing from **VS2013** and I can't simply bring them back.

Now my **VS2008** has the features that I want:
[image]

But no trace of them in **VS2013 Professional**:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have eventually fixed my issue by following Graham's suggestion on my question on his post [Installing SQL Server Data Tools – Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/installing-sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-03-13/) by taking *scorch earth* approach and uninstalling  every single edition of SQL that I had on my PC. The whole thing basically boils down to these three simple steps,

1. Uninstall every SQL Server instance from your PC using *Programs and Features* in *Control Panel*
2. Installed 32-bit edition of **SQL Server 2014 Express** (any other variation would work)
3. Installing 32-bit **SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013** and choosing *Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server* since the 32-bit versions match. If you got mismatch editions follow the post mentioned above.  (there is no 64-bit variation for SSDT-BI since Visual Studio is also only available in 32-bit.)

Viola,

[image]